# For rebol3: Want to get started with native extensions on linux. How do I write a hello-world?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I know how to write some 100 lines C, but I do not know how to read/organize larger source like Rebol. Somewhere was a tutorial with hostkit and dll, but it seems R3 is now statically linked. So I do not know where to look.

How would I write a native which gets a value and returns another? Where to put it in the source? What to obey, like telling the GC I created something in C?

Also, how can I embed R3 in other programms, to call it from Python or Node? I ask for Python/Node part comes later. But my learning-main should access R3 in a similar way. Means dll. And are there some typical hooks for startup/shutdown etc in such ffi's?

[Edit: forgot to mention: it is for Rebol 3.]

Comment: Maybe the Art of Linux Programming can help get you started? It discusses linking programs together over various interfaces. http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that i have a specific interface, that of rebol3. But good read :)

Comment: "I do not know where to look." - use the source, Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's two questions.  :-)

---

Regarding the first (about adding a native)... it's probably best elaborated as developer documentation on a Wiki.  Questions in the [rebol](/questions/tagged/rebol) tag should generally be more about the language from a user's point of view.  The answers regarding source code itself typically will be long, and there's really only a few people who can answer it, or care about the answer (what StackOverflow calls "too localized").  And it will wind up being more of a [c](/questions/tagged/c) question at that point, if anything.

So telling the developers to get their act together and write that documentation and put it in a centrally organized place is probably the best idea!  :-P  But I actually did try this myself.  I added a set-env native to set environment variables from the interpreter, and you can look at the diffs it took to do that in GitHub for a bit of an idea.

[add SET-ENV, tweaks to host api for environment string handling](https://github.com/rebol/r3/commit/9f39818a2605867994fd5ab6db089ef669fc8535)

An important thing to remember is that when you touch certain files, you have to run **make prep** which does a lot of scanning and code generation automatically.  Adding a native is one of those things where you're definitely going to have to do that, each time you change to an interface that fundamental.

---

As for your second question, which is more of a user-facing question about interpreter embedding, one of the first places to look is just in how the simple [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is implemented.  There are two versions in the main repository right now, one for Posix and one for Windows.

https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/os/host-main.c

So a string goes in and a string comes out.  But there are more complicated forms of interaction, and you can get to them from **reb-host.h**, which includes these files from [src/include](https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/include/)

```
#include "reb-config.h"

#include "reb-c.h"
#include "reb-ext.h"        // includes reb-defs.h
#include "reb-args.h"
#include "reb-device.h"
#include "reb-file.h"
#include "reb-event.h"
#include "reb-evtypes.h"
#include "reb-net.h"
#include "reb-filereq.h"

#include "reb-gob.h"
#include "reb-lib.h"
```

So you can look through those files for the API as it existed at the moment of the December-12th open-sourcing.  Things will be evolving, and hopefully much better documented.  But for now that's what seems to be available.  You could link the host kit as a shared/DLL or static library, it depends on your build settings and what compiler you use.

Comment: dealing with settings to make a dll is question 3 :)
But i am busy enough for now with #1, making my own function. thanks :)